# Materialize css tabs are not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, materialize

I am making profile ui for mobile. I am using materialize css for that.. But in my case it's not working. I mean the tabs are not working.

So here is the code.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VmmJWv

html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <title>Profile</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">

</div>
<div class="profile">

<div class="cover-img">
<img id="cover-img" src="https://cdn2.xyztimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Material-Wallpaper-11.1-696x407.png" width="100%" height="150px" >
</div>
<div class="profile-meta z-depth-3">
<div class="profile-img">
<img id="profile-img" src="http://orig02.deviantart.net/e65e/f/2016/145/0/f/profile_picture_by_the_spooky_man-da3t6n4.png" height="100px" width="100px">
</div>

<div class="profile-name">
<p class="profile-name">Profile Name</p>
</div>
<div class="profile-id">
<p class="profile-id">Profile ID</p>
</div>
<div class="profile-desc">
<p class="profile-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in sollicitudin lectus, et gravida mauris. </p>
</div>
<ul class="profile-stats">
  <a><li><span>1m</span>Followers</li></a>
  <a><li><span>100</span>Following</li></a>
  <a><li><span>758</span>Posts</li></a>
  <a><li><span>84</span>Helpful</li></a>
</ul>

<div class="profile-btn"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn center-btn purple">Follow</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>

      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>

  <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');
});

</script>
```

Thanx for the help........

Comment: You need to include jquery. Look at your javascript console. It is full of errors. Working: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZBBgRb

Comment: Thanx i forgot lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to add jQuery `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.js"></script>`

Comment: You probably would include a more recent version: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/jquery/

Answer (score 6):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
      <ul class="tabs">
        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
        <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>

        <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
    <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>

    <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var el = document.querySelector('.tabs');
    var instance = M.Tabs.init(el, {});
  </script>
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. JQuery is not mandatory for tabs in cards to work. Weirdly enough, this Tabs initialization was not in Materialize documentation. Thanks anyway Muhammed.

Answer (score 2):

You just needed 1 modification in you html.

You are missing to include the Jquery which is required. You can check these issues easily in developer console.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/css/materialize.min.css">

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.8/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

  <title>Profile</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="profile.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="nav">

</div>
<div class="profile">

<div class="cover-img">
<img id="cover-img" src="https://cdn2.xyztimes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/Material-Wallpaper-11.1-696x407.png" width="100%" height="150px" >
</div>
<div class="profile-meta z-depth-3">
<div class="profile-img">
<img id="profile-img" src="http://orig02.deviantart.net/e65e/f/2016/145/0/f/profile_picture_by_the_spooky_man-da3t6n4.png" height="100px" width="100px">
</div>

<div class="profile-name">
<p class="profile-name">Profile Name</p>
</div>
<div class="profile-id">
<p class="profile-id">Profile ID</p>
</div>
<div class="profile-desc">
<p class="profile-desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec in sollicitudin lectus, et gravida mauris. </p>
</div>
<ul class="profile-stats">
  <a><li><span>1m</span>Followers</li></a>
  <a><li><span>100</span>Following</li></a>
  <a><li><span>758</span>Posts</li></a>
  <a><li><span>84</span>Helpful</li></a>
</ul>

<div class="profile-btn"><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn center-btn purple">Follow</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<br>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col s12">
    <ul class="tabs">
      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test1">Test 1</a></li>
      <li class="tab col s3"><a class="active" href="#test2">Test 2</a></li>

      <li class="tab col s3"><a href="#test4">Test 4</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
  <div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>

  <div id="test4" class="col s12">Test 4</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs();
});
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('ul.tabs').tabs('select_tab', 'tab_id');
});

</script>
```

Updated Codepen : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOONjj

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. On my case there was another JS code interrupting the Materialize JS. Avoid unnecessary JS code for the page containing the tabs.